# Knitting RMarkdown with ggvis to Word

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, ggvis, vega

When I try to knit a RMarkdown document with `ggvis` plots to Word, I get the following message from Rstudio.

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
Execution halted
```

Does there exist an elegant solution (without too much effort) to make this possible, perhaps using `export_png` and `vg2png`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
```

The following table looks fine...
As long as I don't include this plot below

```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
p <- pressure %>%
  ggvis(x = ~temperature, y = ~pressure) %>%
  layer_bars()
export_png(p, file = "hoge.png")
```

![](hoge.png)
````

[image]

If you will use this frequently, you can define hook.

Comment: "Error in vega_file(vis, file = file, type = "png") : 
  Conversion program vg2png not found. " Where can I get vg2png for Windows?

Answer (score -1):

1. First go to [Node JS Download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. After instaling node.js, in terminal run:

   `npm install vega`