# ggvis plots refusing to knit to Word

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, ggvis

I'm attempting to KNIT rmarkdown to Word with ggvis, and getting the below error:

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
Execution halted
```

Below is reproducible code to try it out.
I am using RStudio.
If you comment the last line, it will work fine.
If you don't, it will fail.

````
---
title: "TestWordOutput"
author: "John"
date: "August 20, 2015"
output: word_document
---

```{r}
library(ggvis)
summary(cars)

plot(cars)

ggvis(cars, ~speed, ~dist)
```
````

I have done some research, and the closest thing I've found is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940473/knitting-rmarkdown-with-ggvis-to-word?rq=1). However, the code in the answer doesn't work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/ggvis/man/export_png.html (or do `?export_png`). Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/vega/vega) to try to get those Vega/node.js utils to work (I couldn't now, but have in the past), then do something like:

````
---
title: "TestWordOutput"
author: "John"
date: "August 20, 2015"
output: word_document
---

```{r}
library(ggvis)
summary(cars)

plot(cars)

ggvis(cars, ~speed, ~dist) %>% export_png("mtcars.png")
```

![](mtcars.png)
````

And it should work for you. But, I'd stick with `ggplot2` graphs if your target is Microsoft Word. They won't be interactive in Word and you can make super-awesome looking `ggplot2` charts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm on a locked down machine, so installing node.js and then a package on top of that is probably more trouble than it is worth. The reason I've been trying to avoid ggplot2 is that I hear it can't do dual axis charts.

Comment: (some of us consider that A Good Thing :-)

Comment: So I've read, but I've yet to see a convincing reason why. Even in [this detailed explanation](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf) I feel his first plot goes against his point. In that plot, the first thing I notice is that revenue continued to climb, despite a decrease in units sold from the prior month. That's an interesting point that I don't feel is as clear in a panel plot. I grant that they can be mis-used, but that doesn't seem good enough reason to throw them out.